# Angularjs 4 - Inject a service without passing parameters on the constructor

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Is there a way to inject a service into a class without having to declare it as a parameter on the constructor?

The usual way works just fine, I have no complains about it. I'm just trying to create a super class to handle some stuff witch depends on a service and I want it to be independent, I don't want to have any references to that service on child classes.

This is the usual way:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private someService: SomeNpmInstalledService) {}

  doSomething() {
    this.someService.do();
  }
}
```

That's what I'm looking for:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Some injection magic annotation here
  private someService: SomeNpmInstalledService;

  constructor() {}

  doSomething() {
    this.someService.do();
  }
}
```

I'll try to explain the reason why I want this kind of functionality with the following example:

```
export class MyComponent extends MySuperClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  doSomething() {
    super.someSuperClassFonctionality(); 
  }
}

export class MySuperClass {
  constructor(private someService: SomeNpmInstalledService) {}

  someSuperClassFonctionality() {
    someService.doStuff(); 
  }
}
```

The above code gives an **error** because in my component, when I call *super()*, I have to pass the parameter defined on the constructor of my super class. But That's **exactly what I don't want to do**. I want my components to don't even know about the service that is used inside the super class.

Comment: How you gonna use it without injecting in constructor?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45225676/3001761

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. It's almost the same yes, but I'n my case I would need the injector to be injected in an other way then be declared in the constructor (if possible)

Comment: I ran into this issue a couple of projects before.  I ultimately decided that there was no clean way of doing this, and I instead just made two services and injected the "superclass" service into the "subclass" service in its constructor and used it as a parallel service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hayhorse. That was my backup approach too but was wondering if someone else had a nice alternative to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: use Injector.
https://angular.io/api/core/Injector

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
```

then in your constructor:

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {
  let this.service = injector.get(ServiceToInject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It's almost what I need, but having the injector in the constructor is still a problem to my need. I edited my original question to add more detail.

Comment: He still have to inject "Injector" via the constructor

Comment: An argument for 'injector' was not provided .. =( I think I'm missing something